# Android TextUtils.split to deliver a fixed length string[]

Tags: android, regex, string, split, textutils

I cannot get a string broken into fixed length chunks and added to an ArrayList ... the code below iterates through as expected, but all the messageToSplit[] upto the last one are null.  The last one actually has a value in it.

In the example below if the edit text returned, "01234567890" then "", "" and "890".

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{4}");
ArrayList<String> myText = new ArrayList<String>();
String[] messageToSplit = TextUtils.split(myStringEditText.getText().toString(), p);
int x = 0;
while(x  <= (myStringEditText.getText().toString().length() / 4)) {
  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), x+": '" + messageToSplit[x] + "'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  myText.add(messageToSplit[x]);
  x++;
}
```

Comment: Should have mentioned that I've also tried "(.?){4}".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a `split` operation, the regex pattern is the *separator*. For example, if the regex pattern were `;`, then `12;34;56` would be split into `12`, `34`, and `56`.

So in your case `01234567890` is split into `""` (the string before `0123`), `""` (the string between `0123` and `4567`) and `890` (the remainder of the string after `4567`).

You probably don't want to use `split` but rather something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".{1,4}");
Matcher regexMatcher = p.matcher(messageToSplit);
while (regexMatcher.find()) {
    myText.add(regexMatcher.group());
}
```

`.{1,4}` will match 4 characters if it can, but make do with 1-3 if four are no longer available (which might happen at the end of the string if its length is not a multiple of 4).